# I can't get the custom control to change rendering of a master page control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a master page with a placeholder control.

I have a page which inherits from master page.

I then have a custom control which is displayed on the page, this custom control has a cast to the masterpage so I can access the placeholder control to turn visibility on and off.  Everything works as expected when I watch it in the debugger, but the placeholder control fails to turn it's visibility off.

I feel this has something to do in the order in which the events are firing.  It appears any code in the custom control on the page is firing after the masterpage has already rendered.

Does anybody have any idea how I can affect the way this page is rendered so the custom control can turn the placeholder and on and off?

the code in the control looks like this;

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var master = this.Page.Master as Site;
    if (master != null)  // cast failed, your master is a different type
    {
        master.NavBar.Visible = false;
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was the order in which the control, masterpage and page were being fired, it was ignoring the setting on the custom control.   The solution is to add this functionality to the custom control on the OnPreRender(EventArgs e) method.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            var master = this.Page.Master as Site;
            if (master != null)  // cast failed, your master is a different type
            {
                var progressShown = master.FindControl("ProgressShown");
                if (progressShown != null)
                {
                    master.NavBar.Attributes.Add("class", "test");
                }
            }

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the MasterType tag in your page, so that you dont need to typecase the page.Master, directly you can get the Master instance.

Comment: i already have this in the page <%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" %> but it's not the page I'm trying to access the masterpage from it's the custom control which is rendered to page.

Comment: First typecast this.Page to the particular page instance and then get the Master instance from the casted page instance.

Comment: like this? var page = this.Page;
            var master = page.Master as Site;
            if (master != null)  // cast failed, your master is a different type
            {
                master.NavBar.Visible = false;
            }

Comment: yeah this just doesn't affect the rendering, whenever the custom control is rendered it has no effect on the masterpage.